# How to find the coordinates of a point at the end of a chord on a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I'm working on a game but have never taken linear algebra and am not sure what math functions I should be using to get the desired result.

In this scenario, a player is shooting a zombie represented by a circle. How do I calculate the x/y coordinates of the exit wound?

[image]

Things that are known:

- The x/y coordinates of the bullet upon collision
- The x/y coordinates of the center of the zombie's circle
- The radius of the zombie's circle

Things that I want to know:

- The x/y coordinates of the entry wound

Bonus points:

- How do I calculate the rotation for the exit wound?

I was thinking of somehow calculating the tangent line of the impact point and using that to calculate the final coordinates, but I'm not sure if that is even the right approach.

In the image below, a is the point-of-impact and b is the exit wound:

[image]

Comment: You need Snell's law: that $\frac{\sin \theta_2}{\sin \theta_1} = \frac{v_2}{v_1} = \frac{n_2}{n_1}$ to find the exit angle *first*, and then find the coordinates of the exit wound. To do this, you would need to find the velocity before and after the collision with the circle.

Comment: Although [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) is used for light waves or other waves, the principle behind it is Fermat's principle of least time, and can be applied to bullets as well (see this [discussion](https://www.scienceforums.net/topic/82816-bullet-and-snells-law/)).

Comment: What do you mean by "exit angle"? Which angle would be the "exit angle"?

Comment: The angle between the tangent to the circle and the chord (passing through $b$).